# CUDA threads sync

Tags: многопоточность, cuda

У меня есть один трёхмерный блок (или несколько, но это не важно, так как они независимы). Мне надо синхронизировать потоки в этом блоке следующим образом : сначала должны исполнится все потоки с координатой z=0, затем z=1 и так далее. То есть надо послойно синхронизировать потоки по оси z. Мне уже несколько человек приводят в пример следующий код:

```
    __global__ void Kernel(){

          for(int z = 0; z < zmax; z++){

             if(threadIdx.z == z){
                //code
              __syncthreads();
             }
          }
      }
```

Если для наглядности сократить это всё, то вместо цикла будет что-то вроде этого

```
       if(threadIdx.z == 0){
           __syncthreads();
       }
       if(threadIdx.z == 1){
           __syncthreads();
       }
       и т. д.
```

Такой код по идее гарантирует синхронное выполнение потоков с одинаковым z, но не гарантирует порядок z. Ведь могут первее к точке синхронизации придти все потоки с z=1, и тогда слой, где z=1 выполнится раньше того, где z=0.

Собственно верны ли мои рассуждения? Если да, то как сделать так как я хочу. Или это невозможно?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался в чём проблема. __syncthreads() должно быть использовано вне if(). Я просто неправильно понял людей, которые не любят лишний раз писать фигурные скобки.

Так правильно.

```
 __global__ void Kernel(){

      for(int z = 0; z < zmax; z++){

         if(threadIdx.z == z){
            //code

         }
        __syncthreads();
       }
  }
```

Тогда всё будет весьма логично. Это будет равносильно следующему

```
    if(threadIdx.z == 0){
       //code
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if(threadIdx.z == 1){
        //code
    }
    __syncthreads();
   и т. д
```

Всё потоки будут будут доходить до каждого if() и исполнятся будут только те, которые нужно. Таким образом можно обеспечить последовательное выполнение по z.